# pg_restore [archiver] did not find magic string in file header

Tags: postgresql, azure, pg-restore

I take backup my azure postgresql flexible server to azure file share within blob storage using the command which is working fine and storing backup at azure file share. The command is running from azure vm and the azure fileshare is mounted on a vm

```
pg_dump -Fc -v --host=postgressqlflex-server.postgres.database.azure.com --dbname=elo-strangler-service-database --username=abc -f test$date.sql
```

But when i am trying to restore the backup form azure fileshare using the command bellow which running on same azure vm. its raising error

```
pg_restore -v --no-owner -h psqlflex-server.postgres.database.azure.com -U abc -Fc -j 4 -d testbackup1669029901.sql
```

```
Error

> pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
```

is it the reason of the two different name of the database for backup and restore?

Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This `-d testbackup1669029901.sql` is wrong. `-d` should point at a database not a file. Also `testbackup1669029901.sql` does not match `-f test$date.sql`.

Comment: You have not addressed the mismatch in the file names.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, "**pg_restore**" does not know what format of dump to use, resulting in the following error: "Did not find magic string in file header."

**In this scenario, "-d" represents a database, not a ".sql" file. **
**-f "Selects the formatted output." format can be one of the outputs of a SQL script file. "**

Updated command to restore the database from .sql file

```
pg_restore -v --no-owner -h psqlflex-server.postgres.database.azure.com -U abc -Fc -j 4 -f testbackup1669029901.sql
```

Comment: I have used the command does not see output on the console and as well database in psql server.the console remain hang.```` pg_restore -v --no-owner -h psqlflex-server.postgres.database.azure.com -U abc -Fc -j 4 -f testbackup-2022-11-22T-11-05-01.sql  ````. the size file the file is 0 kb

Comment: same error after pressing enter couple of times on the console.```pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header```

Comment: `-f` **does not** represent `format` it means `file` where with `pg_restore` that means restoring as plain text to the file named instead of a database.  `-F` represents `format`. You do not want to do `-f testbackup-2022-11-22T-11-05-01.sql` as the *.sql file is the input not the output.

Comment: It would be really kind.if you write down the full command.thanks in advance

Comment: getting this error now----> pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)

Comment: `` `pg_restore -v --no-owner --host=psqlflex-server.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=abc --dbname=backup-db testbackup2022-11-23T-10-25-01.dump ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related with the operator `>` under Windows PowerShell to output to a file.
When you use -f filename option on pg_dump the file is saved correctly and pg_restore works fine.
I used in both -F c option.